# Event listener memory leak in React & Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm trying to use React and Redux for building a WebGL/Three.js based game.

So far I've created a simple toy application to figure out how to handle input, rendering, state management etc. See [this repository](https://github.com/lysigk/react-redux-three).

Things are running fine and smoothly as long as no events are triggered. However, for some reason, as soon as events like `mousemove` are fired, memory usage constantly goes up and performance decreases.

The yellow line in the performance profile shows this constant piling up of events.

[image]

Unfortunately, at this point my application is a bit too complex for a JSFiddle or something like that. If it would be helpful, I could upload the application on firebase.

But maybe someone has seen something like this before and has an idea what exactly is causing this memory leak.

**EDIT:** I tried using `addEventListener()` instead of React's synthetic events and the event listeners actually stopped piling um. But that's a very ugly workaround and not really satisfying.

Also, I realized that my application used a huge amount (more than 600 MB) of memory because of another bug. Running my app, the dev server, VSCode and some other background tasks at the same time made my laptop quickly reach it's limits. After fixing the bug the event listeners still keep piling um, but get removed by GC after a while. So maybe working at the limit of my computers memory stopped GC from doing that...

Comment: mousemove is afecting the state?

Comment: Yes, mousemove dispatches an action that affects the Redux state. And the modified state is then used to update the Three.js scene before rendering the next frame and calling requestAnimationFrame()

Comment: maybe those changes are forcing the re-render of the component where the canvas is, try block the re-renders using this https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate

Comment: I'm already using shouldComponentUpdate() to re-render only after the update action is dispatched, not on every single event. But the problem's still there.

When calling the .render() method of the WebGLRenderer the target canvas gets updated, however, not by a 'regular' React re-render but rather by the renderNextFrame() function inside of my component.

I think most of the relevant code is inside of [this script](https://github.com/lysigk/react-redux-three/blob/master/src/containers/ThreeApp.js).

Comment: can you check if ThreeDisplay is re-rendering? just in case

Comment: Yes, I've refactored ThreeDisplay into a class component so I can use liefecycle methods to check for updates. And yes, it actually seems as if ThreeDisplay gets re-rendered on every click or mousemove event.

I'm not sure why this is, because it's a child component of ThreeApp and I thought it will only re-render if the parent component get's re-rendered.

Is there any way to prevent ThreeDisplay from re-rendering on mouse events? Would it make sense and be possible to move the event listeners into the parent component?

Answer (score 1):

You wouldn't happen to be using a React 16 development build, would you?

I am seeing a similar memory leak pattern but I am using React + P5.js to do animation. I removed all my components one by one until I was left without any listener callbacks yet still, the memory leak remained.

My original code was on codepen before I moved it onto a local dev server, at which point I noticed the memory leak, so running out of ideas, I tried testing it on codepen and surprisingly, the leak was gone.

Codepen was using minified React 15.3.0 while my local dev was using 16 dev build. I built a production version and now the listener count is constant. Upon further testing, I found that in dev mode, the listener count reaches a peak after hitting around 2700 listeners then drops back down, so React must be holding onto it for debugging purposes then GCing it.

I can provide my codepen that illustrates the problem if needed.

Comment: I'm using React 15.6.2. I guess the common thing between Three.js and P5.js would be the `<canvas>` element, so maybe that's in some way part of the problem.